# Error: Could not find or load main class, Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to build Casandra project on a Centos server. I downloaded the file from here.

http://apache.bilkent.edu.tr/cassandra/2.0.6/

Here is the README.txt file

```
This short guide will walk you through getting a basic one node cluster up
and running, and demonstrate some simple reads and writes.

  * tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-$VERSION.tar.gz
  * cd apache-cassandra-$VERSION
  * sudo mkdir -p /var/log/cassandra
  * sudo chown -R `whoami` /var/log/cassandra
  * sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/cassandra
  * sudo chown -R `whoami` /var/lib/cassandra

Note: The sample configuration files in conf/ determine the file-system 
locations Cassandra uses for logging and data storage. You are free to
change these to suit your own environment and adjust the path names
used here accordingly.

Now that we're ready, let's start it up!

  * bin/cassandra -f
```

As README.txt file suggested I followed these instructions as adapting to my case (I am not root).

```
tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-2.0.6-src.tar.gz
cd apache-cassandra-2.0.6-src
mkdir -p var/log/cassandra
chown -R `whoami` var/log/cassandra
mkdir -p var/lib/cassandra
chown -R `whoami` var/lib/cassandra
```

Since I am not root on the server, I can not create my files under `/var` folder. So, I created new folder `var` under `apache-cassandra-2.0.6-src` and put my `lib` and `log` files there. Then I followed next instructions from README.txt file.

```
bin/cassandra -f
```

However whatever I tried it is no good, I always get this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

How can I fix this problem?

My java version

```
java -version

java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT:**
As an extra informaiton, I tried this instructions on my pc, too. Exactly same thing with README.txt file using `sudo` and **it worked.**

Comment: Hm. Does the suggestion to set `CASSANDRA_HOME` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851308/i-am-getting-this-error-when-i-am-starting-cassandra-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291474/cassandra-installation-issue help?

Comment: @JasonC I tried what you said, not working. CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/pat/to/lib (where jar files included)

Comment: What about `CASSANDRA_HOME`? (By the way, the `.jar` file itself should go on the classpath not the path to it; but don't do that here -- I suspect that setting `CASSANDRA_HOME` correctly will do all that for you, as I'm presuming `cassandra` is a script of some sort that sets up the classpath as per that environment variable).

Comment: Yeah, I tried it actually before I ask question.

Comment: echo $CASSANDRA_HOME 

/home/some.path/apache-cassandra-2.0.6-src/

Answer (score 12):

I see you have downloaded the source package (*apache-cassandra-2.0.6-src.tar.gz*), but the instructions you posted seem to assume it is already built.

You need to build the source package before you can use it; there would be a separate set of instructions for that somewhere.

I suspect you'd rather just run it instead of building it from source. You may have meant to download the binary package [*apache-cassandra-2.0.6-bin.tar.gz*](http://apache.bilkent.edu.tr/cassandra/2.0.6/apache-cassandra-2.0.6-bin.tar.gz) instead (note "bin", not "src" -- this is a traditional naming convention when separating binaries from source in downloadable archives). With that package you can just run it right out of the box. For the source package you'd need to follow the build instructions to compile cassandra first.

I also suspect that you downloaded the binary package on the PC side, which is why it worked there.

If you do need to build from source:

1. Install `ant` and `ant-optional` if you do not already have it.
2. Extract the source archive somewhere, then in the base directory (where `build.xml` is):

   ```
   ant release
   ```
3. Make a cup of coffee (the `rat` task at the end takes forever).
4. Binary archives will be created in `build`, and a built distribution can be found in `build/dist`.

Comment: OMG! you are right thats why it worked on my pc. Thanks for the answer but actually I need to build it from the source code to be able to use jvmti agent. By the way, the instructions are the same. Same readme.txt files... How am I suppose to know what to do now? why do they have same readme files

Comment: A quick glance in the source package shows a `build.xml` in the root directory. Try `ant release` there (install `ant` if you don't have it already). I believe it will build into a `build` subdirectory.

Comment: I get this error when I try ant release time. 

`Could not create type regexpmapper due to No supported regular expression matcher found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpMatcher`

Comment: @genclik27 [Install the `ant-optional` package.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ant/+bug/231454)

Comment: I cant, I am not root. If this will solve my problem, I can talk to someone who has root rights

Comment: @genclik27 You'll have to get somebody with root access to install that for you. Don't get frustrated, this is about par for the course as far as building from source on Linux goes (actually this is pretty mild).

Comment: Okay, then I talk to server admin.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to do it? i am not getting this thing can somebody explain?

Comment: @WorkingHard.. How to do what? What thing are you not getting? If you're having a specific problem, please [do some research](http://www.google.com), and if you are still having an issue, ask a new question.

Answer (score 7):

do a export CASSANDRA_HOME=location of cassandra

should work in 2.0.6 i verified just then without setting that variable and after setting those variables.

```
$ export CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/local/cassandra/dsc-cassandra-2.0.6
$ /usr/local/cassandra/dsc-cassandra-2.0.6/bin/cassandra


or
$ cd /usr/local/cassandra/dsc-cassandra-2.0.6
$ export CASSANDRA_HOME=
$ bin/cassandra
```

in fact you can also set CASSANDRA_HOME= in cassandra-2.0.6 directory. set it to empty value if you are executing the export command from the cassandra directory.

Answer (score 4):

Path for CASSANDRA_HOME was incorrect for me. After i set the correct path it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the `cassandra.yaml` configuration file, change the

```
commitlog_directory
data_file_directories
saved_caches_directory
```

properties to the path you have specified as they are no longer `/var/lib...`

You will need to set them to point to wherever the directories actually are.

Comment: I tired these but I get again same error. And as I said in the question, I also tried these on my pc using sudo. So, I think, error should be at somewhere esle

Comment: I tried from all over on my pc and this time it worked. I suppose your are right, it is about something new var folder. But how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact problem, where I wanted to install cassandra in userspace without any sudo privileges. I did the following

In cassandra.yaml I changed the following config to local path

```
commitlog_directory
data_file_directories
saved_caches_directory
log4j.appender.R.File
```

Installed the "bin" tar files for the particular OS env and not the "src" file.

```
Export CASSANDRA_HOME=/userspace/cassandra-2.x
```

Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when I used Jdk 1.8_281 version.
The problem was resolved when I downgraded to jdk 1.8_241 version.